# Is it illegal to encrypt data using a public key which has a use only for non commerical use comment on top

Tags: public-key-encryption

CONTEXT: We have a business customer to whom we need to send an encrypted file. 
The business customer has send us a public key file that has a usage statement "Non commercial usage only". Our software is legit to encrypt stuff.

QUESTION: would it be illegal for us to encrypt stuff using client's public key

Comment: If you require legal advice, you should ask a certified lawyer of your jurisdiction. You won't be able to receive binding legal advice here or on any other stackexchange site unfortunately. In any case, maybe talk to your customer first and voice your concerns to them?

Answer (score 0):

Best consult a lawyer. But a lot of those legal sounding notices are completely unenforceable, they're just there to scare people. In general, once someone sends something without a prior agreement, the receiver owns it entirely, as long as the sender has ownership of it. That is regardless of whether the sender changes their mind after the fact. Post conditions, which you can only read after receiving something even if they are sent at the same time, are not a prior agreement (you need the option to decline) before the transaction).

The important part is what rights the sender has. It's possible the sender doesn't have the rights to ask you to use the key as they asked you to. Again, a lawyer can clarify, I don't think you would be liable for that infraction, but the notice might be enough to mean you "should have known", and might have some liability.

Even better, ask your customer for clarification. I'm surprised you didn't do that in the first place. If they offer to indemnify you - that is, take responsibility for all liability you might incur by violating that notice - you should be in the clear, providing a lawyer agrees.

I'll say "lawyer" again, because the legal system takes about ten years full time study for a lawyer to just get started knowing it well enough to start practicing, and decades longer to get good at it. You can't expect anyone with a casual opinion about it to know enough.